# How to convert a numerical reference in a string to an integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a series of text files that include numerical references. I have word tokenized them and I would like to be able to identify where tokens are numbers and convert them to integer format.

```
mysent = ['i','am','10','today']
```

I am unsure how to proceed given the immutability of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try
`[item if not item.isdigit() else int(item) for item in mysent]`

Answer (score 1):

If you try to convert a `string` that is not a representation of an `int` to an `int`, you get a `ValueError`.

You can try to convert all the elements to `int`, and catch `ValueError`s:

```
mysent = ['i','am','10','today']

for i in mysent:
    try:
        print(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 10

If you want to directly modify the `int` inside `mysent`, you can use:

```
mysent = ['i','am','10','today']

for n, i in enumerate(mysent):
    try:
        mysent[n] = int(i)
    except ValueError:
        continue

print(mysent)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ['i', 'am', 10, 'today']

**.isdigit() IS NOT THE SAME AS try/except!!!!**

In the comments has been pointed out that `.isdigit()` may be more elegant and obvious. As stated in [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), *There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it*.

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit), `.isdigit()` *Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.*

Meanwhile, the `try/except` block catches the `ValueError` raised by applying `int` to a non-numerical `string`.

They may look similar, but their behavior is really different:

```
def is_int(n):
    try:
        int(n)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

**EXAMPLES:**

> Positive integer:

```
n = "42"

print(is_int(n))   --> True
print(n.isdigit()) --> True
```

> Positive float:

```
n = "3.14"

print(is_int(n))   --> False
print(n.isdigit()) --> False
```

> Negative integer:

```
n = "-10"

print(is_int(n))   --> True
print(n.isdigit()) --> False
```

> `u` hex:

```
n = "\u00B23455"

print(is_int(n))   --> False
print(n.isdigit()) --> True
```

These are only some example, and probably you can already tell which one suits better your needs.
The discussion open around which one should be used is exhausting and neverending, you can have a look a this couple of interesting SO QA:

- [try/except comparsion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095453/is-there-a-way-other-than-try-except-and-isdigit-to-check-user-input-in)
- [input validation analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: I don't think you should use a `try... except` block here, especially since you are essentially ignoring the caught `ValueError`. I think it is better to see if the item is an integer/all digits using `str::isdigit`.

Comment: @Thomas actually is a topic that has [been widely discussed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response), and the `try/except` block has been proven to be the best solution.

Comment: There is no continuous `while True` loop asking for user input in this question. Following [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) the "obvious way to do it" in this case is to use `str::isdigit` as it seems more intuitive, is provided by the prelude, and possibly more performant.

Comment: @Thomas There are a [lot more discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095453/is-there-a-way-other-than-try-except-and-isdigit-to-check-user-input-in) on SO on which one should be used. I do understand that without updating the answer, some doubt may remain: I'll update the answer with proper documentation.

Comment: @Thomas If you're still interested in this, I've updated the answer showing some of the differences between `.isdigit()` and `try/except`!

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Yeah, the ongoing discussion about this online is pretty interesting. I would think that Python had a standard way of testing a string as an integer, but apparently not. `str::isdigit` is probably not the best solution (though is apparently fit-for-purpose for this question) because it doesn't handle negative integers, and `n.is_numeric()` with `int(float(n))` is worse. I think you're right: until Python 3.7+ comes up with a standard way of doing this, `try... except` is the best solution.