# if isinstance statement in Python is True but it does not pass

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I'm struggling with the extra credit of excercise 35 from the book "Learn Python the hard way". Based on the advise provided in previous comments ([learn python the hard way exercise 35 help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300506/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-35-help)) I tried two options:

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next_move = raw_input("> ")
    if isinstance(next_move, int):
        how_much = int(next_move)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")


    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")
```

My issue is that the line: `if isinstance...` is never passed! It is always skipped. I always get as a result `Man, learn to type a number` (even if I type in a number).

I do succeed with the code below:

```
next_move = raw_input("> ")
char = list(str(next_move))
for v in char:
    if v in str(range(0, 10)) and v != " " and v != ",":
        how_much = int(next_move)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
```

However, I would like to understand why the first option does not work :(

Comment: The raw input is a string, how could it ever be an instance of integer? It's not true, that's why it doesn't pass. Your second solution is just horrible, frankly - even `v in '0123456789'` would have been preferable.

Comment: Being an integer and being a string with only numbers are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Raw input is going to be a string, so it's normal for your test to fail. A more pythonic approach is:

```
next_move = raw_input("> ")
try:
    how_much = int(next_move)
except ValueError:
    dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
```